# Rx Java parsing a List to RealmList

Tags: realm, rx-java, realm-list, tolist

So, here is my code:

```
@Override
public RealmList<RealmStuff> call(List<Stuff> stuff) {
    return Observable.from(stuff)
            .map(this::getRealmStuff)
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .first();
}
```

Which is fine. however I want to get a RealmList. 
How can I achieve that? 
Should I go with a flatmap and just go with an oldschool for-each and add item one by one to new RealmList?

Maybe something like this:

```
    .map(realmStuff -> new RealmList<>(realmStuff.toArray(new RealStuff[realmStuff.size()])))
```

But this looks insane to me... Or is it just me?

Comment: well, if the method's purpose is just to convert `List` to `RealmList`, I don't see any benefit with using reactive approach.

Comment: Usually when using Rx you are passing Observable through the whole chain to benefit from the async and push-oriented nature. If all you want is doing computations being serial or parallel then you can check out [Java 8 Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html).

Comment: RxJava is not a Stream Api, it shouldn't be used like this. Rule of thumb: if you're using toBlocking() in rx chain probably you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `RxJava` for this you could make it using `collect` operator:

```
//pseudocode
Observable.from(stuff)
    .collect(() -> {
            return new RealmList(); //list initialization
        }, (realmList, stuffItem) -> {
            realmList.add(stuffItem); //adding each item to list
        }
    ).blockingGet()
```

But the reactive approach is redundant here, just use a regular forEach loop.